# React animate element when property changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to fade in an element when a property changes ?

I'd like the element returned by the `statusMessage()` function to fade in each time the `this.props.statusMessage` changes.

Currently no animations are applied.  It doesn't appear as though any classnames are added either.

```
class SelectPlayer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    selectedId = this.props.selectedId;
    selectedPlayerName = this.props.selectedPlayerName;
    Store.dispatch(Actions.updateScore(selectedId, selectedPlayerName));
  }

  statusMessage() {
    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName='message'
        transitionAppear={true}
        transitionAppearTimeout={2000}
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
          <div key="1">{this.props.statusMessage.text}</div>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.selectedPlayerName) {
      return (
        <div className="details">
          <div className="name">{this.props.selectedPlayerName}</div>
          <button className="inc" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Add 5 points
          </button>
          { this.statusMessage() }
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div className="message">Click a player to select</div>
      );
    }
  }
};
```

CSS

```
.message {
  line-height: 2.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.message-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.message-appear.message-appear-active{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue a few weeks ago. The issue is that the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` needs to be rendered before it's children. In your example both `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` and `this.props.statusMessage.text` will be rendered at the same time when `this.props.selectedPlayerName === true`.

I found this article that might be useful: [here](https://web-design-weekly.com/2015/02/05/applying-react-js-css-transitions-initial-render/)

> Recently while using the ReactCSSTransitionGroup add-on for React.js, I ran into the issue of not being able to apply the enter transitions to the child elements when the component is first rendered to the DOM.
>
> When the component is initially rendered, both the
>   ReactCSSTransitionGroup and all of its child elements appear in the
>   DOM at the same time. However, the ReactCSSTransitionGroup will only
>   apply the appropriate animation classes to any child elements which
>   enter the DOM after the initial render.

Comment: ok, so I'm not crazy, I feel better, thanks!  This seems like it should be waaay easier than it is.  But, I'm brand new to React so I will read the article and see about a fix.

Answer (score 11):

This might be easier with [react-animate-on-change](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animate-on-change) (disclosure: I'm the author).

In render you would do something like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.props.selectedPlayerName) {
    return (
      <div className="details">
        <div className="name">{this.props.selectedPlayerName}</div>
        <button className="inc" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Add 5 points
        </button>
        <AnimateOnChange 
          baseClassName="message" 
          animationClassName="message-clicked" 
          animate={this.props.selectedId === this.props.id}>
            {this.props.statusMessage.text}
        </AnimateOnChange>
      </div>
    );
  }
  else {
    return (
      <div className="message">Click a player to select</div>
    );
  }
}
```

And then use animation in your CSS:

```
.message-clicked {
  animation: clicked-keyframes 1s;
}

@keyframes clicked-keyframes {
  from {opacity: 0.01}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

It's hard to imagine how you want the result to be. But to the sounds of it, you have a player list which can be clicked and then a view of selected players? In that case, you should rather use an array with selected players and use ReactCSSTransitionGroup to render players entering/leaving the array.

Comment: hey @arve0 what if I want the animation to happen when the `src` attribute of an image is changed?

Comment: Depends on how `src` is changed. Via DOM? Via a prop? Check out the documentation on [animate-on-change](https://github.com/arve0/react-animate-on-change). If something is unclear, please [open an issue](https://github.com/arve0/react-animate-on-change/issues/new) with code to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 8):

The official documentation states that you need to provide a **key** for each element inside ReactCSSTransitionGroup

React uses this **key** for the DOM manipulation. So it should be unique. Also from my experience you should have transitionAppear and transitionEnter configured the same way, so that initial animation and animation for the change looks the same.

So you need to provide some unique keys (or at least different between current state (or props) and next state (or props) of the child element for each change) for the ReactCSSTransitionGroup

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example"
                         transitionAppear={true}
                         transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                         transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
                         transitionEnterTimeout={500}>
    <h1 key={key}>Hello, {name}</h1>
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

You can check out [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dssimushkin/69z2wepo/252736/) to see how it works.

**NOTICE** that I've used
{this.state.name} as a key, so it works ok in my example. But in a real world application I think you should use something else as a key

Answer (score 1):

Heres a similar solution to @Sim Dims with the current version of ReactTransitionGroup.

```
function Example() {

        const [tick, setTick] = useState(true);

        return (
            <div>
                <CSSTransition
                    in={tick}
                    appear={true}
                    timeout={2000}
                    classNames="fadein"
                    unmountOnExit={false}
                >
                    <div className="box"></div>
                </CSSTransition>

                <button onClick={() => {
                    setTick(!tick)
                }}>Show</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

You just toggle a meaningless boolean to trigger the update and use identical enter and exit animations.

```
.fadein-appear,
.fadein-enter,
.fadein-exit {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fadein-appear-active,
.fadein-enter-active,
.fadein-exit-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.fadein-appear-done,
.fadein-enter-done,
.fadein-exit-done {
    opacity: 1;
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/modern-dust-0yfjg